# AdMob - Check if an app has been disabled

Tags: android, admob

I would like to know if there is a way to check if my app is disabled for serving ads from AdMob. I have an old app published in the Google Play Store which used to have ads on it, now I started to work on that app again and I have been trying to add AdMob again with unsuccessful results. I am getting the following error while trying to serve ads on a real device.

Note: If I add the real device as a test device, test ads are shown correctly, also test ads are shown correctly in the emulator.

```
There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
Failed to load ad: 0
```

I have been looking for a solution through several threads on the internet, some of them suggest that my app has been disabled for serving ads from AdMob and I should have received an email with information about that, this application has been unattended for several months so I may have lost that email, do we have a way to check the status of an specific app from the AdMob console?.

Note: The status of my account is 'Open' in AdMob console.

This is my app current dependencies and code if helps:

Gradle dependencies:

```
...
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
...
```

LoginActivity.java

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-X~Y");
...
```

MainFragment.java

```
...

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
...
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.x.y.MainActivity"

android:background="@color/tw__composer_deep_gray">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/titleCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/usernameTitle"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/imageCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleCardView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_button_background"
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what about your app status in the admob console....usually you should see if your app is suspended..Even if your account is open, a single app could be removed there...

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Where can I see that 'status', I am not able to see apps related status anywhere in the AdMob page, thanks.

Comment: @Carioni Added, thanks.

Comment: What can you see in the admob monitize console? doest it say that they received your request?

Comment: my deactivated ones have a line under "impressions". If you got no impressions, there is a "0" if it´s still active....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Well, that line depends on the date tresshold I select, if I put 'last week' tresshold I do see just a '-' under impressions, if I select 'All time' tresshold I do see data about impressions, I do not know if that is a good indicator to check if the app is disabled or not, don't you think so?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I did not took that into account, thanks, it says nothing, no requests printed, what does that means?

Comment: mmm...well, that´s correct...from all I have read, it seems that single ads will not be suspended, only complete account...

Comment: @AlejandroMorán , try to wait for 3-4 hours. may be your device has got some incorrect libs. Which device are you using?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I am currently testing with a Sony Xperia M4 Aqua with a custom ROM, I do not know if it is hardware related since I've deployed a release in Google Play and I do not get impressions from users, it is quite strange.

Comment: @AlejandroMorán , you are right. this is strange. try to create new account/and or new user.

Comment: @AlejandroMorán , i would suggest to use sample for admob banner

Comment: @AlejandroMorán https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples

Comment: @Vyacheslav I downloaded the banner example, created a new app in AdMob console, replaced the AppId and AppUnitId with the newer ones but no real ads shown, tests ads are correctly shown. Let's see in a few hours.

Comment: @AlejandroMorán ,oh. very strange. i would suggest to wait 24 hours to register your new appid. May be your account was banned. So, I really don't know why this bug appears.

Comment: @Vyacheslav After a few hours it shows ads in the BannerExample app, I tried to copy the AppId and AppUnitId to my app but that does not work, does that means my app is disabled for serving ads?

Comment: @AlejandroMorán recheck appid and ads id and write to admob support about your account. Strange.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

If you just created an AdMob ads unit, you have to wait some hours to be able to use it.

Or you just added the wrong ads id.

Comment: Ad Units are not recently created, I have tried with Ad Units created some days ago

Answer (score 0):

According to [this official Google document](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en), error code 0 stands for:

> ```
> Error Code 0 : ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR
> ```
>
> This indicates that something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.
>
> Newly created Ad Units can take upto 2 hours to become active (SpinUp Time). Any Ad requests from newly created Ad Units would also receive Error Code 0 in response to Ad requests until they are ready to serve live ads.
>
> What to do? Test Ads!!